# Display message when AJAX return empty data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple AJAX code that fetch data from DB and display it in a DIV, I want to display an error message when no data found:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'models/fetchUsers.php',       //the script to call to get data
    data: $("#searchForm").serialize(), //add the data to the form
    dataType: 'json',                   //data format
    success: function(data)             //on recieve of reply
        {
            if(data.trim()==''){alert("Nothing Found");} //DOESN't WORK
            $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
            $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
                    });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it behaves like this because if the data is empty, it will not return as success. you can use the error property;

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'models/fetchUsers.php',       //the script to call to get data
data: $("#searchForm").serialize(), //add the data to the form
dataType: 'json',                   //data format
error: alert("Nothing Found"),      //error message when data is empty
success: function(data)             //on recieve of reply
    {
        if(data.trim()==''){alert("Nothing Found");} //Does this work when data is whitespace?
        $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
        $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
                });

    }
});
```

Comment: my only question is; does the previous error message work when the data is whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

you should check  empty data in serverside(php) and if yes echo it  as false , then you can check in as data =='false' like following code.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'models/fetchUsers.php',       //the script to call to get data
        data: $("#searchForm").serialize(), //add the data to the form
        dataType: 'json',                   //data format
        success: function(data)             //on recieve of reply
            {
                if(data=='false'){alert("Nothing Found");} //DOESN't WORK
                $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
                        });

            }
        });
</script>
```

Return false from serverside for failure condition by `echo 'false';`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can return some empty flag when the data is null